# How to convert vector to array

Tags: c++, arrays, stdvector

How do I convert a `std::vector<double>` to a `double array[]`?

Comment: Kinda begs the question of why?  You can access a vector as an array.  What does an array do that a vector does not?

Comment: @Michael The typical use case I have is using a vector in my own code and needing to call a third-party function that takes an array

Comment: The terminology being thrown around is confusing. A pointer isn't an array. Do we want a pointer to the first element of an array, or an array?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan incredibly, sometimes is necessary. For example when passing as argument to a CUDA kernel

Comment: Zombie comment from 11 years ago - I love it :)

Comment: This functionality is particularly useful for vectors to `char*` when you have to build an argc/argv array and filter some options first.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan zombie comments never die.  It's easier than trying to mix std::array with legacy code in some instances.

Answer (score 678, accepted):

There's a fairly simple trick to do so, since the spec now [guarantees](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#69) vectors store their elements contiguously:

```
std::vector<double> v;
double* a = &v[0];
```

Comment: I tried this method. but all elements in the vector didn't copy to array. How to copy all the elements to the array?

Comment: @ganuke You're not copying, you're making a pointer that points to the actual array the vector is using internally. If you want to copy [GMan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923272/how-to-convert-vector-to-array-c/2923295#2923295) explains how

Comment: @ganuke: What is "the array"? You need to provide more information. What's the big picture?

Comment: void GMap::train( double* inputVector);
this is the function I need to call. But I have a vector of double.
so I need to copy that vector to a array.

Comment: @ganuke You don't, you just need a `double*` that points to the same data. This answer works for exactly that case

Comment: oops.. is that so.. Then its ok. I'm new to C++ programing. thanks for helping me.

Comment: @chris: There's two sorts of raw 2D arrays, and when you add `std::vector` and `std::array` into the mix, there's lots of combinations.  For some sorts: yes.  For most: no.

Comment: got an error:
    error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'cv::Vector<_Tp> (*)[3]' to 'short *'

Comment: Writing to an array vs. writing to vector sped up calculations 4 times in the debug mode. And this was a simple vector<bool> v. As for reading operations speed increase was about x 2. So don't dismiss arrays. After all OpenCV uses both forms and I suspect not only due to comnpatability but also for efficiency reasons.

Comment: Since this line does not copy data, does that mean I don't need to delete a after I'm done with it?

Comment: @guneykayim The vector owns that memory, you shouldn't free it

Comment: Is it guaranteed that &v[0] points to continuous range of memory? I'm getting memory corruption with semi-long vectors...

Comment: @DenisV Yes, as long as it's not a vector of `bools`; they're special-cased for space efficiency. It's one of the first things mentioned in the spec (23.2.4 Class template `vector`): "The elements of a vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if `v` is a `vector<T, Allocator>` where `T` is some type other than `bool`, then it obeys the identity `&v[n] == &v[0] + n` for all `0 <= n < v.size()`."

Comment: `std::vector<double> v;
double* a = v.data();`

Comment: @ThatPixelCherry it doesn't work for bool because vector<bool> is implemented using a bitmap.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek : This is an incorrect answer. Suppose u initialize a vector in foo() which is in a.cpp and and call it from b.cpp the vector is cleared after it is out of scope u will be trying to use memory u shouldn't in b.cpp. So even though this is a short nice trick in O(1). This non copying trick may not work in a lot of scenarios!

Comment: The vector.data() answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/40031309/564626) is better for C++11

Comment: @Vlad "this was a simple vector<bool> v" -- vector<bool> isn't "simple", it's bit-packed, so your efficiency factors are completely wrong.

Comment: And "the new spec" at the time of answering was?

Comment: Is it possible that vector decides to reallocate its internal array due to memory management? If that happens the pointer will become invalid?

Comment: using &v[0] is undefined behavior if the std::vector or std::array is empty,if using c++0x  better to use v.data().https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/containers#vector-is-contiguous

Comment: The link in the anwer points to the whole general doc. Perhaps a link to where this was guaranteed would be useful

Comment: @KansaiRobot The link actually does point to the right issue, but the page is ridiculously long and most browsers won't jump down to the section until the page is fully loaded. It's issue #69

Comment: Great answer but for some reason, it doesn't work inside functions, i.e. if the vector and the array are the arguments of some function.

Answer (score 206):

What for? You need to clarify: Do you need a pointer to the first element of an array, or an array?

If you're calling an API function that expects the former, you can do `do_something(&v[0], v.size())`, where `v` is a vector of `double`s. The elements of a vector are contiguous.

Otherwise, you just have to copy each element:

```
double arr[100];
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), arr);
```

Ensure not only thar `arr` is big enough, but that `arr` gets filled up, or you have uninitialized values.

Comment: Note: use v.size() to get the number of elements for the new array: double arr[v.size()];

Comment: @rbaleksandar: Arrays can't have a non-constant expression size.

Comment: @GManNickG : It works but I think there is some misunderstanding here. Imagine the following: you have a class with a bunch of pointers of various types that have to point to arrays, which are not known at the time you define your class and which are later on created by flushing various vectors and using their size-parameter to determine how much space is to be used. Another example: a simple function void arrayTest(unsigned int arrSize), that creates an array (short arr[arrSize];) in it by using its function-parameter for the size.

Comment: @rbaleksandar No misunderstanding; in C++11 and prior, array sizes must be integral constant expressions. Your function example is a common use for VLAs in C, but only supported by (nonstandard) extension in C++. It may come to C++14 though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17318040/87234. But as of now, it's simply not a standard option.

Comment: Note: Use "malloc" or "new" to dynamically allocate memory with size v.size(), and then copy all there. And keep in mind to "free()" or "delete" the pointer when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: @Jet: Why? Just use std::vector.

Comment: @GManNickG, This post states "double arr[100];" where 100 is fixed size, so using "new double[v.size];" will make it more flexible as it will not have limit of 100

Comment: @Jet: you should use `std::vector<T>` in place of `new T[]`, don't do manual memory management.

Comment: @GManNickG I think @Jet is saying that if you want to convert a vector to an array, and you intend to size the array using the `size()` function of the `std:vector` you'll need to use `new` or `malloc` to do that. As it was already pointed out (by you) that `double arr[v.size()]` is not valid.

Using vector in place of new is a good idea, but the entire point of the question is how you can convert a vector into an array.

Comment: Would memcpy not be a beter solution then std::copy?

Comment: @convert Not necessarily. Many times `std::copy` becomes `memmove` or `memcpy`, and `std::copy` is more generic for people who are using this answer with something you cannot memcpy.

Comment: @GManNickG Agree, but since it´s about double, memcpy would be a more performat solution, or am I wrong? And std::copy from performance point of view beter then just a simple for loop?

Comment: @convert It's highly dependent on context and if the compiler can deduce a `memcpy` vs [`memmove` call](https://godbolt.org/z/Wdf585jTE). Again, `std::copy` is simpler and always works - if profiling results say this needs to be a memcpy then go for it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13131253/87234 for example.

Comment: @GManNickG https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy says it´s the fastest way to copy, that´s why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 170):

For [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), [`vector.data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) will do the trick.

Comment: Note: It doesn't copy the data of vector, it only stores pointer that points to the actual array the vector is using internally.

Answer (score 23):

```
vector<double> thevector;
//...
double *thearray = &thevector[0];
```

This is guaranteed to work by the standard, however there are some caveats: in particular take care to only use `thearray` while `thevector` is in scope.

Comment: ...and make sure the vector isn't `empty()`, otherwise this would invoke the dreaded UB.

Comment: (undefined behavior)

Answer (score 23):

As to `std::vector<int> vec`, vec to get `int*`, you can use two method:

1. int* arr = &vec[0];
2. int* arr = vec.data();

If you want to convert any type **`T`** vector to `T* array`, just replace the above `int` to `T`.

I will show you why does the above two works, for good understanding?

**`std::vector` is a dynamic array essentially.**

Main data member as below:

```
template <class T, class Alloc = allocator<T>>
class vector{
    public:
        typedef T          value_type;
        typedef T*         iterator;
        typedef T*         pointer;
        //.......
    private:
        pointer start_;
        pointer finish_;
        pointer end_of_storage_;

    public:
        vector():start_(0), finish_(0), end_of_storage_(0){}
    //......
}
```

The `range (start_, end_of_storage_)` is all the array memory the vector allocate;

The `range(start_, finish_)` is all the array memory the vector used;

The `range(finish_, end_of_storage_)` is the backup array memory.

For example, as to a vector vec. which has {9, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4} is pointer may like the below.

[image]

So `&vec[0]` = start_ (address.) (start_ is equivalent to int* array head)

In `c++11`  the `data()` member function just return start_

```
pointer data()
{ 
     return start_; //(equivalent to `value_type*`, array head)
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Vectors effectively are arrays under the skin. If you have  a function:

```
void f( double a[]);
```

you can call it like this:

```
vector <double> v;
v.push_back( 1.23 )
f( &v[0] );
```

You should not ever need to convert a vector into an actual array instance.

Answer (score 5):

```
std::vector<double> vec;
double* arr = vec.data();
```

Answer (score 4):

We can do this using data() method.  C++11 provides this method.

### Code Snippet

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
  ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

  vector<int>v = {7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
  int *arr = v.data();

  for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
  {
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function, then you probably need this:`foo(&array[0], array.size());`. If you managed to get into a situation where you need an array then you need to refactor, vectors are basically extended arrays, you should always use them.

Answer (score -2):

You can do some what like this

```
vector <int> id;
vector <double> v;

if(id.size() > 0)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < id.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < id.size(); j++)
        {
            double x = v[i][j];
            cout << x << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: v [i][j]; for 2d array