# Convert std::vector to array

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have a library which expects a array and fills it. I would like to use a std::vector instead of using an array. So instead of

```
int array[256];
object->getArray(array);
```

I would like to do:

```
std::vector<int> array;
object->getArray(array);
```

But I can't find a way to do it. Is there any chance to use std::vector for this?

Thanks for reading!

---

EDIT:
I want to place an update to this problem:
I was playing around with C++11 and found a better approach. The new solution is to use the function std::vector.data() to get the pointer to the first element.
So we can do the following:

```
std::vector<int> theVec;
object->getArray(theVec.data()); //theVec.data() will pass the pointer to the first element
```

If we want to use a vector with a fixed amount of elements we better use the new datatype std::array instead (btw, for this reason the variable name "array", which was used in the question above should not be used anymore!!).

```
std::array<int, 10> arr; //an array of 10 integer elements
arr.assign(1); //set value '1' for every element
object->getArray(arr.data());
```

Both code variants will work properly in Visual C++ 2010. Remember: this is C++11 Code so you will need a compiler which supports the features!

The answer below is still valid if you do not use C++11!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert vector to array C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923272/how-to-convert-vector-to-array-c)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes:

```
std::vector<int> array(256); // resize the buffer to 256 ints
object->getArray(&array[0]); // pass address of that buffer
```

Elements in a `vector` are guaranteed to be contiguous, like an array.

Comment: But be careful with zero size arrays.

Comment: What if vector gets relocated?

Comment: @alxx: How can it be reallocated from within `getArray`? I assume that's what you mean, since it's not a problem outside of it.

Comment: @alxx: if reallocated, as if `array` was reseated (in the event it's not allocated on the stack) then the pointer would now be invalid. @GMan: I would suggest passing the size, even though it's absent from the original question.

Comment: Be reminded that this only works for std::vector<T> with T!=bool as std::vector<bool> is a special case, where 8 bools are squeezed into one byte.

Comment: @GManNickG: what if we have a `vector<vector<int>>`??

Comment: Can we get all the data contiguously in an array?

Comment: @Manolete: You can get the inner vector's pointer to it's array of int's, and you can get the outer vector's pointer to it's array of `vector<int>`'s, but there's no way to get a contiguous array of every single `int`, because that's not what that container says it is. That would be `vector<int>`. *Usually* it's better to replace nested vectors with a single vector, but not always.