# convert std vector to char and viceversa

Tags: c++

I have a library function from which I should pass same data types to the main application .

Thus my question is - how do I pass `a std::vector<char>` to a C style function that expects `char*`. Here is what I have tried

```
// function to apply on char
void somefunction (char* c_buf, int* c_buf_len)
// main function 
typedef std::vector<char> Buf;
void (Buf& buf)
{

    // first convert `buf` to char and call function 
    somefunction(char_buf, char_buf_len)
    // Now convert buf to vector and do something with it..
}
```

Comment: Make it at least **look** like code. And it shouldn't be tagged with `c`

Comment: I don't follow... convert `std::vector` to a single `char`? How exactly? Or to a `char *`? Does the `std::vector` contain `char`s?

Comment: One may explain what is the vector type, then one may manipulate `vector` instead of `char *`, as it is much safe IMHO

Comment: what about &(Buf[0]) ? Should work,I guess

Comment: @RuggeroTurra: why did you change the C function signature to use `int` instead of `int*`?  It is not uncommon for such a parameter to be used for both input and output, to specify the buffer initial size and then return the size written.  That usage requires a pointer.

Comment: I think changing the content of the question every minute does not contribute to valuable answers.

Comment: I really do not know why this question has been marked as duplicate by Remy Lebeau . Is this complete answer ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787074/convert-stdvector-to-array

Answer (score 3):

You cannot convert a vector to `char`. They're completely unrelated types. Good news is that you seem to need a pointer to a character buffer and a `vector<char>` is exactly that. You get the pointer to the begginning of its storage by taking the address of the first element (`&buf[0]`) or by saying `buf.data()`. `buf.size()` will give you (you guessed it!) the size of the buffer. That's all you need to call `somefunction`.

Comment: I think you should mention that `&buf[0]` requires that the vector is not empty.

Comment: The `[]` operator does not perform bounds checking, so it won't matter what address it returns if `size()` is 0.  The `at()` method, on the other hand, does perform bounds checking and will raise an exception.

Answer (score 2):

To pass a `std::vector<char>` to a function that expects a `char *`, you can

1) Pass the address of the first element in the vector.  The only caveat is that using this method requires that the vector is not empty.

```
if (!buf.empty())
   somefunction(&buf[0], buf.size());
```

2) If using `C++ 11` use the `data()` method for the vector.  In C++ 11, using `data` guarantees that it will work with an empty vector.

```
   somefunction(buf.data(), buf.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int len = buf.size();
somefunction(&buf[0], &len);
```

You can do that because (From n2798 (draft of C++0x)):

> **23.2.6 Class template vector [vector]**
>
> 1 A vector is a sequence container that supports random access iterators. In addition, it supports (amortized)
>   constant time insert and erase operations at the end; insert and erase in the middle take linear time. Storage
>   management is handled automatically, though hints can be given to improve efficiency. ***The elements of a
>   vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if v is a vector where T is some type other
>   than bool, then it obeys the identity &v[n] == &v[0] + n for all 0 <= n < v.size()***.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
void (Buf& buf)
{
    int len = buf.size();
    somefunction(&buf[0], &len);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You should pass `len` instead of `&len`.

Comment: This seems to arise from a change in the question.  However your answer looks good.

Comment: `&len` is needed if the function expects an `int*`.  Otherwise, if it expects an `int` then `buf.size()` can be passed directly, yes.