# How to pass a vector of strings to execv

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have found that the easiest way to build my program argument list is as a vector of strings. However, execv expects an array of chars for the second argument. What's the easiest way to get it to accept of vector of strings?

Comment: You can't "get it to accept" anything it wasn't written to accept. You could, however, convert your input into a format it understands.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`execv()` accepts only an array of string pointers.  There is no way to get it to accept anything else.  It is a standard interface, callable from every hosted language, not just C++.

I have tested compiling this:

```
std::vector<string> vector;
const char *programname = "abc";

const char **argv = new const char* [vector.size()+2];   // extra room for program name and sentinel
argv [0] = programname;         // by convention, argv[0] is program name
for (int j = 0;  j < vector.size()+1;  ++j)     // copy args
        argv [j+1] = vector[j] .c_str();

argv [vector.size()+1] = NULL;  // end of arguments sentinel is NULL

execv (programname, (char **)argv);
```

Comment: It looks like you're passing the program name twice to execv, since argv[0] is set as the program name.

Comment: When I try to compile the program, it complains about `argv[0] = programname`. It says `test.cpp:10: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘=’ token`

Comment: @z-buffer:  Dunno.  It compiles fine for me.  The only things I haven't shown are includes for `unistd.h`, `string`, and `vector` and `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @wallyk: ...and the fact that the code is inside a function! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798231/why-wont-this-c-program-compile

Comment: @Greg:  Quite right.  I wrapped the code inside `int main(void) {` ... `return 0;}` so it would compile *and* link.

Comment: Is the cast in the call to `execv` legit? The documentation expects an array of constant pointers to modifiable characters, the cast removes that cast and allows `execv` modifying memory that is marked as `const`... not that there would be any reason for `execv` to modify the data but...

Comment: the use of c_str() concerns me, argv[j+1] could become invalid.

Comment: @symphonyblade: Look closely at how argv[] is allocated.

Comment: don't we need to free the memory taken by `argv` using `delete`? Where can we do that?

Comment: @YoniZohar:  If `execv` works (without error), the process is overwritten, so no.  If `execv` fails, then maybe `delete` would be needed.

Comment: I would replace `const char **argv` with `std::vector<const char*>`, and then call `execv()` with `argv.data()`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be done pretty cleanly by taking advantage of the internal array that `vector`s use. Best to not use C++ strings in the vector, and `const_cast` string literals and `string.c_str()`'s to `char*`.

This will work, since the standard guarantees its elements are stored contiguously (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2923290/383983)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

int main() {
  vector<const char*> command;

  // do a push_back for the command, then each of the arguments
  command.push_back("echo");
  command.push_back("testing");
  command.push_back("1");
  command.push_back("2");
  command.push_back("3");

  // push NULL to the end of the vector (execvp expects NULL as last element)
  command.push_back(NULL);

  // pass the vector's internal array to execvp
  execvp(command[0], const_cast<char* const*>(command.data()));
  return 1;
}
```

Code adapted from: [How to pass a vector to execvp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846934/how-to-pass-a-vector-to-execvp/10196175#10196175)

Do a `const_cast` to avoid the "deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'". String literals are implemented as `const char*` in C++. `const_cast` is the safest form of cast here, as it only removes the `const` and does not do any other funny business. `execvp()` will not edit the values anyway.

If you want to avoid all casts, you have to complicate this code by copying all the values to `char*` types not really worth it.

Although if the number of arguments you want to pass to `execv`/`execl` is known, it's easier to write this in C.

Comment: If you use `vector<const char*>` instead, then you can get rid of all the `const_cast`s.

Comment: @RemyLebeau would you like to review the new version?

Answer (score 2):

The prototype for `execv` is:

```
int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);
```

That means the argument list is an array of pointers to null-terminated c strings.

You have `vector<string>`.  Find out the size of that vector and make an array of pointers to char.  Then loop through the vector and for each `string` in the vector set the corresponding element of the array to point to it.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that `std::string` stores it's data typically without the null-terminator. You'd have to use `std::string::c_str()` or include the null-terminator in each string in the vector manuall, prior to calling `execv()`.

Comment: "*`std::string` stores it's data typically without the null-terminator*" - since C++11, `std::string` is required to store a null terminator in its data buffer. But even before C++11, most implementations did that anyway, to keep `c_str()` simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the how execv works (not easily anyway), but you could overload the function name with one that works the way you want it to:

```
int execv(const string& path, const vector<string>& argv) {
    vector<const char*> av;
    for (const string& a : argv) {
        av.push_back(a.c_str());
    av.push_back(0);
    return execv(path.c_str(), &av[0]);
}
```

Of course, this may cause some confusion. You would be better off giving it a name other than execv().

NB: I just typed this in off the top of my head. It may not work. It may not even compile ;-)

Comment: it does not compile. something is wrong about converting `&argv[0]` from const char** to char* const*

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled over the same problem a while ago.

I ended up building the argument list in a `std::basic_string<char const*>`. Then I called the `c_str()` method and did a `const_cast<char* const*>` on the result to obtain the list in a format that `execv` accepts.

For composed arguments, I `new`ed strings (ordinary strings made of ordinary chars ;) ), took their `c_str()` and let them leak.

The `const_cast` is necessary to remove an additional `const` as the `c_str()` method of the given string type returns a `char const* const*` iirc. Typing this, I think I could have used `std::basic_string<char*>` but I guess I had a reason...

---

I am well aware that the `const`-casting and memory leaking looks a bit rude and is indeed bad practise, but since `execv` replaces the whole process it won't matter anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

1. `std::vector<std::string>` to grab all the arguments I need.
2. Creating `std::vector<const char *>` right before `execv()`, reserving enough space in it for all the arguments.
3. Converting the second vector using `std::transform()`.
4. Feeding it to `execv()` using `const_cast<char* const*>(vec.data())`.

Transform pass:

```
std::transform(stringsVec.cbegin(), stringsVec.cend(), charsVec.begin(),
    [](const std::string &arg)
{
    return arg.c_str();
});
```

This is basically a combination of @ericcurtin's and @Ferruccio's answers.