# Compare size of types at compile time

Tags: c++, arduino, c-preprocessor

I am working on some code that requires 64 bit floating point calculations, but on some of the platforms where it's being deployed there isn't a 64 bit float type.
I have a version of code that uses a software emulated 64-bit type, but I want to be able to combine the hard and soft versions as a single include the switches type definition between hardware and software float.
Both float and double are available, but on the one platform they are both 4 bytes in size and on the other they are 4 and 8.

I know I can't use `sizeof()` in a preprocessor macro so I looked at comparing the max value for both, but in the Arduino framework `FLT_MAX` and `DBL_MAX` don't seem to be defined?

How can I perform this check at compile time?

Comment: `sizeof(TYPE)` is evaluated at compile time. Use static assertion together with it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c

Comment: why you cant use `sizeof` in a macro? and why is this a problem? just dont use macros

Comment: Since you tagged C++, you can use `if constexpr`, or template specializations, or tag dispatch, or something else.

Comment: i'm using the arduino ide so i'm stuck with the version of gcc it comes with which does not support c11

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm still not so sure, what of the c++ standard can be applied in that weird _arduino world_. Never tried myself. STM32 works all well with an appropriate cross compiler.

Comment: what version is it ? If you are using a 10 year old compiler you should consider upgrading anyhow

Comment: and i need to conditionally define a type as either a hardware floating point type or the software emulation, i don't see how i can do that without a macro

Comment: The linked question has a poor-man version of the static assert

Comment: and a static assert would make compilation fail, it doesn't let me fall back on the soft float type

Comment: I think I understand the question now. Yes, the assertion is not the answer

Comment: @JamesKent: The Arduino IDE has supported C++11 for _years_; [it's even been the default for almost four](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26175586/560648). I don't understand why people keep making the Arduino platform out to be some kind of puritan medieval footnote.

Comment: @TheDude same standard. avrgcc fully supports all the core language features of C++17

Comment: @JamesKent Well, instead of a failing _static assertion_, you could employ SFINAE and a default specialization.

Comment: *"and i need to conditionally define a type as either a hardware floating point type or the software emulation, i don't see how i can do that without a macro"* How about `using float64_t = std::conditional_t<sizeof(double) == 4, double, my_soft_float>;` or something similar?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit my apologies, last time i looked into using a newer language feature it wasn't available, i must have been mistaken what version

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i get an error: `'conditional_t' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type`

Comment: Did you include `<type_traits>`?

Comment: To be clear a 4 byte (32-bit) `double` is **not compliant** with the C spec.  At least 40-bits are needed.

Comment: @chux i know its not, thats why the workarounds with the soft float are necessary

Comment: (My comment should've said `sizeof(double) == 8`, can't fix it now.) So, does it work if you `#include <type_traits>`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat added that include, same error message

Comment: That means it lacks C++14 support... Then maybe `using float64_t = typename std::conditional<sizeof(double) == 4, double, my_soft_float>::type;`?

Comment: targeting an arduino board type_traits doesn't exist and without it: `'conditional' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type`

Comment: however when targeting the esp32 this does work

Answer (score 0):

This is for C, but probably works for C++ as well.

The idea is to test one or more of the `FLT_*` macros against their `DBL_*` brethren. If they are the same, you are likely on the system that does not distinguish between float32 and float64. What about

```
#include <float.h> /* or <cfloat>?  */

#if FLT_MANT_DIG == DBL_MANT_DIG
  /* Funny system */
#else
  /* Sane system */
#endif
```

Check your float.h contents for a suitable pair.