# invalid operands of types 'float' and 'const c'

Tags: c++, string, floating-point

I just started learning C++ and I need some help.

`targetDistance` is a `float` variable and I want to add a string `"a"` to it, is it possible?

I tried this:

```
  targetDistance = targetDistance <<"a"
```

It gives me this error:

```
 invalid operands of types 'float' and 'const c'
```

Comment: No, this is impossible. I wonder what your intention is to "add" a string to a floating point number? Sounds like a misconception to begin with.

Comment: Do you want `targetDistance` to become a string after you do that?

Comment: There are some really [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4641116) available to help learn how to program in C++.

Comment: as in like, in python i would do `targetDistance = targetDistance+"a"`

Comment: @strilz: C++ is different from Python. In Python, assignment to a variable also sets its type. In C++, the type doesn't change, so it has to match. (at least roughly - minor conversions like int to float are allowed)

Answer (score 1):

If targetDistance is a float, you need to convert it to a string before you can concatenate it with another string.  For example:

```
auto result = std::to_string(targetDistance) + "a";
```

Comment: Note to OP: `auto` tells the compiler to guess the type. In this case `std::string` is guessed, so it's equivalent to writing `std::string result = ...;`.

Comment: got this error message `'to_string' is not a member of 'std`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat guess -> infer before the 5 minutes is up?

Comment: @strilz • `std::to_string`  is declared in `<string>`, and you need to be in C++11 compiling mode or later (I use C++17 compiling mode for my programs).  How to specify which C++ standard you are compiling against varies by compiler.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat • guess -> deduce

Comment: I am using the c++ software they have with the Arduino

Comment: @Bathsheba Wanted to use a simpler word at first, and didn't see your comment until 5 mins were up. Oh well.

Comment: @strilz: You need to enable C++11 and `#include <string>` for the code in my answer to work.  For how to enable C++11 with Arduino, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224746/how-to-use-c11-to-program-the-arduino

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to convert the float variable(in this case targetDistance) into a string.
Make sure that you have included this header:

```
#include <string>
```

The code below:

```
string s; //to store our float variable
s= to_string( targetDistance ); //to_string function converts into string 
s= s+ "a";
```

Here is just the short version of it:

```
string s = to_string( targetDistance ) + "a" ;
```

Comment: `string` -> `std::string` etc.