# use shared_ptr array for execl()

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a `shared_ptr` to an array of `char`, like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<char[]> tmp [ 10 ] ;
```

I have populated `tmp`, and now want to pass the data to `execl()`, which takes a `char * const *`.  What's the right way to do it?

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797837/how-to-pass-a-vector-of-strings-to-execv) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846934/how-to-pass-a-vector-to-execvp) might help you.  You can probably get away with just creating a new array a pointers.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797837/how-to-pass-a-vector-of-strings-to-execv) is what i do now . but this don't cause Memory leak ?@RowlandShaw

Comment: I'm not sure.  From what I know `execle()` replaces the process so I do not know exactly what happens to the memory.

Comment: but this is important for me , it's a server program so I have to be sure that  all the memory that is not used can be freed

Comment: @Nathan Should be safe. IIRC the program arguments are (at least in some implementations) copied to a RO area either way.

Comment: @DanielJour That is what I though but I'm not confident enough to actually give an answer.

Comment: @Inochi then just copy to an appropriate array (s). It's unlikely that this will be a bottleneck, no?

Comment: @DanielJour maybe you are right . but I think copy more than 30 arrays it's not a good idea.Although they are not very long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a `shared_ptr` to an array of `char`

What you have is a static array of 10 default-constructed `std::shared_ptr` objects.  Is that what you really want?

Or do you need a single `std::shared_ptr` object that holds a pointer to a single array?

```
std::shared_ptr<char[]> tmp(new char[10]);
```

> I have populated `tmp`, and now want to pass the data to `execl()`, which takes a `char * const *`.

No, it does not.  It takes 2+ `const char*` parameters.  Look at the declaration more carefully:

```
int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...);
```

There is a *big* difference between `const char*` and `char * const *`.

> What's the right way to do it?

The `std::shared_ptr<char[]>::get()` method will return a `char*`,  which can be passed to a `const char*` parameter.

---

**Update**: if you are trying to pass 10 seperate `char[]` arrays to `execl()`, one for each argument, then your static array is fine. Simply call `tmp[index].get()` for each argument you want to pass to `execl()`:

```
std::shared_ptr<char[]> tmp[10];
// populate tmp, then ...
execl(file, tmp[0].get(), tmp[1].get(), ..., tmp[9].get());
```

Alternatively, use `execv()` instead:

```
std::shared_ptr<char[]> tmp[10];
// populate tmp, then ...

char* args[11];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    args[i] = tmp[i].get();
args[10] = nullptr;

execv(file, args);
```

Which is especially useful if you don't know the number of arguments ahead of time:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<char[]>> tmp;
// populate tmp, then ...

std::vector<char*> args;
for (auto &p : tmp)
    args.push_back(p.get());
args.push_back(nullptr);

execv(file, args.data());
```

Comment: You mean I don't need to split the args?

Comment: @Inochi are you trying to pass 10 seperate `char[]` arrays to `execl()`, one for each argument? If so, that doesn't really change what I said in my answer. If you have an array `tmp[10]`, call `tmp[index].get()` for each argument. I updated my answer.

Comment: But it's ok to do this ? it don't cause Memory leak that I must avoid

Comment: @Inochi it is perfectly fine, there is no leak