# how do i convert std::vector to char ** in a reliable way?

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I have been trying to avoid using char ** arrays, however because i am using execvp, i wrote a method to convert a vector of strings to a null terminated char **.

Unfortunately i have until recently been getting segmentation faults, which makes me suspicious that my method doesn't always work for one reason or another:

```
void vectorToNullArray(std::vector<std::string> const &v, char **a) {
  int i = 0;
  while (i < v.size()) {
    std::string str = v[i];
    char *cstr = new char[str.size()+1];
    strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());
    a[i] = cstr;                       // <-- segfault here
    i++;
  }
  a[i] = nullptr;
}
```

if i can be completely free of char ** in the first place, that would be ideal. Why is this code segfaulting?

EDIT: this is how i call it:

```
  char **argvA;
    vectorToNullArray(_ARGV, argvA);
```

where `_ARGV` is an `std::vector<std::string>`, a member variable of some class.

**EDIT 2:  working solution**

```
std::vector<char *> nullTerminatedArgV(std::vector<std::string> const &v) {
  std::vector<char *> result;
  for (auto const &s : v) {
    result.push_back(const_cast<char *>(s.c_str()));
  }
  result.push_back(nullptr);
  return result;
}
```

usage with execvp:

```
    std::vector<char *> argv = nullTerminatedArgV(_ARGV);
    char **command = argv.data();

      int status = execvp(command[0], command);
      perror("execvp error");
```

essentially the accepted answer, with additions from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47714627/5133238

Comment: Show how this function was called. In particular, how was the `a` argument generated?

Comment: *why is this code segfaulting?* -- Let's see a [mcve].

Comment: Don't use a `char**`, use a `std::vector<char const*>`.  That vector of pointers is a soap bubble -- any perturbation of the `std::vector<std::string>` will invalidate it.

Comment: Is there *any reason at all* why you’re using a `while` loop instead of a (range-based) `for` loop?

Comment: @PeteBecker edited accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Pete Becker says, the issue's probably that you haven't called it properly - and specifically that the `a` argument doesn't point to a sufficiently large array of `char*`s to write to.

Anyway, do you really need to screw around with dynamic memory allocation here?  Having `std::vector` manage memory for you is much easier, safer, and more concise.  Perhaps you can do something like below, then pass the result's `.data()` value to `execvp`?  You do need to make sure the vector of strings passed as an argument is not mutated by the caller after this call and before calling `execvp`, otherwise the pointers you collect may be invalidated.

```
std::vector<const char*> getVectorOfPointersToStrings(std::vector<std::string> const& v) {
    std::vector<const char*> result;
    for (const auto& s : v)
        result.push_back(s.c_str());
    result.push_back(nullptr);
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: execvp doesn't seem to like the result.data() passed into it. Ive updated the post above

Answer (score 1):

```
char **argvA;
vectorToNullArray(_ARGV, argvA);
```

`argvA` has some random value; passing it to `vectorToNullArray` results in undefined behavior.

The code doesn't allocate the array itself, but assigns values to it.