# tokenizing string with boost fails when casting tokens to char* const*

Tags: c++, boost, boost-tokenizer

I'm using `boost::tokenizer` to tokenize a string in C++, then I want to pass it to `execv`.

Consider the following code snippet (compilable):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

// I will put every token into this vector
std::vector<const char*> argc;
// this is the command I want to parse
std::string command = "/bin/ls -la -R";


void test_tokenizer() {
  // tokenizer is needed because arguments can be in quotes
  boost::tokenizer<boost::escaped_list_separator<char> > scriptArguments(
              command,
              boost::escaped_list_separator<char>("\\", " ", "\""));
  boost::tokenizer<boost::escaped_list_separator<char> >::iterator argument;
  for(argument = scriptArguments.begin(); 
    argument!=scriptArguments.end(); 
    ++argument) {

    argc.push_back(argument->c_str());
    std::cout << argument->c_str() << std::endl;
  }

  argc.push_back(NULL);
}

void test_raw() {
  argc.push_back("/bin/ls");
  argc.push_back("-l");
  argc.push_back("-R");

  argc.push_back(NULL);
}

int main() {
  // this works OK
  /*test_raw();
  execv(argc[0], (char* const*)&argc[0]);
  std::cerr << "execv failed";
  _exit(1);
  */

  // this is not working
  test_tokenizer();
  execv(argc[0], (char* const*)&argc[0]);
  std::cerr << "execv failed";
  _exit(2);
}
```

When I run this script it calls `test_tokenizer()`, it will print 'execv failed'. (Although it prints the arguments nicely).

However if I change `test_tokenizer` to `test_raw` it runs fine.

It must be some easy solution but I didn't find it.

PS.: I also drop this into an online compiler with boost support [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kkgq7xu4kJyC1rue).

Comment: Nitpicks: The use of `argc` is confusing, as it's commonly used for the second argument to `main()`. The use of `_exit()` is non-portable; prefer the (standard and functionally identical) `exit()`. The use of `execv()` should `#include <unistd.h>`. The construct `(char* const*)&argc[0]` is wrong (well, questionable at least) on too many levels to explain in one comment. And yes, avoid C strings (`char *`) in C++ programs, they just give you headaches. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::tokenizer` saves the token by value (and by default as `std::string`) in the token iterator.

Therefore the character array that `argument->c_str()` points to may be modified or invalidated when the iterator is modified and its lifetime will end with that of `argument` at the latest.

Consequently your program has undefined behavior when you try to use `argc`.

If you want to keep using `boost::tokenizer`, I would suggest to keep the tokens in a `std::vector<std::string>` and transform them to a pointer array afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I would happily drop the tokenizer if there is something more suitable out there.

Comment: Anyway storing them in a vector<string> is nice, but then I'll have to construct an array of 'const char*' for execv. Here is the related stackoverflow topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797837/how-to-pass-a-vector-of-strings-to-execv, so I would prefer something more 'recent' or modern.

Comment: @Daniel: The issue here is the transition from what is "proper" and convenient in C++, and what is "proper" for `execv()` (which isn't C but C++). What's the best way to go forward would depend on the *real* use-case...

Comment: @DevSolar: yes. you are absolutely right. Let's say I have a string variable *command*. What I want is to execute this *command*. It may contain arguments, even within quotes. Language is C++, OS Linux.

Comment: @Daniel If it is basically an arbitrary shell command that you want to execute, you could simply `execl` a shell with `-c` option and pass the whole `command` as single argument. That way you are delegating the issue to the shell. (Prefix `exec` to the `command` if you don't want to create a child process in the shell.) Do not do that if the `command` comes from a untrusted source that shouldn't be able to execute arbitrary code.

Comment: As an alternative where a `std::vector<std::string>` is required, you can use `boost::split` instead of `tokenizer`.