# Creating the execv argument array when the arguments are unknown at compile time

Tags: c++, arrays, c, constants, execv

I am trying to revive an in-house CAM application, i.e. get it to compile on a current gcc so I can maintain it. I have 27 years of experience as an occasional C/C++ hack ;-)

The part in question is the command-line core, so no UI. It has a sort of front-end that does some checking and manipulation of its input arguments, and moves them into a new argv, used by execv to switch to 1 of the 2 different executables where the real work is done.

The existing code accounts for 5 different CL options, although from what I've seen only 2 are normally used. When trying to populate the new argv (char* const new_argv[32]) any way other than with a brace-enclosed list in the declaration, the compiler says I can only do it with a brace-enclosed....

I've googled for 2 days with no compelling results. Is there a slick way to do this, or just the ugly brute force way? Is there something seriously wrong with the whole design?

Comment: See: [How to pass a vector of strings to execv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797837/how-to-pass-a-vector-of-strings-to-execv)

Comment: I'm not sure what you have in mind by "the ugly brute force way".  Normally you'd just loop over the array, assigning to each element a pointer to the desired string.  Note you will have to drop the `const` from the declaration in order to be able to populate it.

Comment: what do you mean with _the ugly, brute force way_?

Comment: Is it possible that you end the sentence _the compiler says I can only do it with a brace-enclosed...._?  What does the compiler says to you... does it print a message?  Can you edit your question and tell what is the exact message the compiler says?

Comment: Good article Remy, thanks. The 'brute force' way I was thinking of was a switch case for all possible arg combinations, and because of scoping, calling exec a different way in each one. Which would be hideous. It didn't occur to me that execv was smart enough to cast the char* to char* const by itself, so @dbush 's answer worked. Thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the type of the array to `char *[]`, then you can assign to each array member before passing it to `execv`.

This is allowed because a `char *[]` can be converted to a `char * const[]` but not a `const char *[]` or `const char * const[]`

Comment: Ok, i would not have thought I could get away with that. Awesome, thanks @dbush

Comment: @MattWalker Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: duh, sorry - the button was also too obvious so i missed it  ;-)