# How to run a system command in C++ as a vector of strings?

Tags: c++

In Python, I can use a list of strings to express a command with its command line options / arguments; on Linux:

```
$ python3 -c 'import subprocess; result=subprocess.run(["/bin/echo", "-n", "-e", r"Hello World\n"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE); print(result.stdout.decode("ascii"))'
Hello World
```

In C++, I'm aware that you can use:

- `int system( const char* command );`, however the entire command has to be a single string, and requires "manual" quoting in case of spaces (see e.g. [C++ system() not working when there are spaces in two different parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964865/c-system-not-working-when-there-are-spaces-in-two-different-parameters))
- the `exec*( )` family of functions; these accept "[an array of string pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797837/how-to-pass-a-vector-of-strings-to-execv)" which is what I'd want - however, these are also "[used to replace the current program within a process with another program](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/secure-programming-cookbook/0596003943/ch01s07.html)" which I do not want

So is there a C++ API where I could pass an array of strings, representing a command line call of a program with its arguments, which would take care of eventual quoting (if the argument contains spaces) automatically? As per the above Python example, in C++ I would like to pass:

```c++
std::vector<std::string> program_to_call = {
  "/bin/echo",
  "-n",
  "-e",
  "Hello World\n"
};
```

... as the program to run, and its arguments.

Comment: `fork()` first, then `exec()`? It's not portable though.

Comment: There is no built in API for this.  System calls are very insecure and you should try and find an alternative.

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver - feel free to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: If you're OK using external libraries you might want to take a look at [boost.process](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/process.html#boost_process.introduction).