# Fastest way to copy the contents of a vector into an array?

Tags: c++, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert vector to array C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923272/how-to-convert-vector-to-array-c)

When working with arrays you have the ability to use

```
memcpy( void *destination, const void *source, size_t num );
```

However vectors simply provide iterators for a copy method, rendering memcpy useless. What is the fastest method for copying the contents a vector to another location?

Comment: In C++, **always** use `std::copy` rather than `memcpy` (the former will delegate to the latter when possible).

Comment: I don't know how fast it is, but you could use `std::copy`.

Comment: I think the most obvious answer here would be: _Why do (you think) you need to copy from the vector into an array?_ A vector _is_ an array, and can be used as such. As a side effect, _no copying at all_ is certainly the fastest possible copying operation.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), hands down. It’s heavily optimised to use the best available method internally. It’s thus completely on par with [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy). There is no reason ever to use `memcpy`, even when copying between C-style arrays or memory buffers.

Answer (score 13):

You'll have to measure that for yourself, in your environment, with your program. Any other answer will have too many caveats.

While you do that, here is *one* method you can compare against:

```
std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), destination);
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:-

```
  std::vector<int> newvector(oldvector);
```

For copying in an array try this:-

```
  std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), destination);
```

Comment: -1. Asker wants an array, not a new vector.

Comment: Sorry I read it wrong then this would be great as answered by Rob:- std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), destination);

Comment: I have just corrected. Thanx for telling!!!:)

Comment: @Alex, how about the vector is used as a package for transfer data through network. e.g A client wants to send a uint32_t and a string? On the server side, to unpack the uint32_t from the package?

Comment: Use network-byte ordering and serialize/deserialize with ntohl, htonl, ntohs, htons etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use memcpy with a vector - vectors are guaranteed to be contiguous in memory so provided that the vector is not empty, you can use `&vData[0]` (where `vData` is your vector) as your source pointer to `memcpy`

**EDIT** As mentioned by comments to other answers, this only works if the vector's value_type is trivially copyable.

Comment: -1 for the same reason mentioned by ildjarn under nosi’s answer.

Comment: @lidjarn OK fair enough - I did not know that and I am sure that there must be others that do not too so I won't actually delete this answer.