# Convert a std::vector to a NumPy array without copying data

Tags: c++, python, numpy, swig

I have a C++ library which currently has some methods inside which return a `std::vector` defined like

```
public:
  const std::vector<uint32_t>& getValues() const;
```

I'm currently working on wrapping the whole library for Python using SWIG and this is working well so far.

SWIG wraps this `getValues()` function fine such that it returns a Python tuple. The issue is in my Python-side code I want to convert this to a NumPy array. Of course I can do this by:

```
my_array = np.array(my_object.getValues(), dtype='uint32')
```

but this causes all the entries in the original vector to be first copied into a Python tuple by SWIG and then again into a numpy array by me. Since this vector could be very large, I'd rather avoid making these two copies and would like for a way to have SWIG create a numpy.array wrapper around the original vector data in memory.

I've read the documentation for [numpy.i](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/swig.interface-file.html) but that explicitly mentions that output arrays are not supported since they seem to be working under the assumption of C-style arrays rather than C++ vectors.

numpy.array's underlying data structure is just a C-style array as is a C++ std::vector so I would hope that it is feasible to have then access the same data in memory.

Is there any way to make SWIG return a numpy.array which doesn't copy the original data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently it is trivial to "cast" a C++ vector to (C) array, see answer on this question: [How to convert vector to array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923272/how-to-convert-vector-to-array-c)

Next you can create a numpy array which will use that C array without copying, see [discussion here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cython-users/Ubh2nG0_R9g), or google for `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData`.

I wouldn't expect SWIG to do all these for you automatically, instead you should probably write a wrapper for your function `getValues` yourself, something like `getValuesAsNumPyArray`.

Comment: Remeber to call `import_array` function before calling any `PyArray_*` function.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` would require you to do your own memory management; if memory management is already handled on the C++ side, that is, Python is not responsible for the memory, you can just use `np.asarray` to get a numpy array that shares memory with the C++ vector, like so:

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
import numpy as np
cdef vector[double] vec
vec.push_back(1)
vec.push_back(2)
cdef double *vec_ptr = &vec[0]    # get hold of data array underlying vec; also vec.data() if you have C++11
cdef double[::1] vec_view = <double[:vec.size()]>vec_ptr    # cast to typed memory view
vec_npr = np.asarray(vec_view)    # get numpy array from memory view
print(vec_npr)    # array([1.0, 2.0])
```

The "Wrapping C and C++ Arrays" section in chapter 10 of Kurt Smith's Cython book provides good examples on this. Also see [Coercion to Numpy from official user guide](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#coercion-to-numpy).

Comment: This caused python to crash for me.

Comment: This works, but `np.asarray` is slow. Use `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` for much better performance.