# How to convert a vector to numpy array with templates and boost?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost

So I found [how to return numpy.array from boost::python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701514/how-to-return-numpy-array-from-boostpython). However, like this I have to write this function for int, float, double separately. Is it possible to avoid this using templates? I would somehow need to convert with T to an entry to the enumeration of NPY data types. Or are there other options?

```
template<typename T>
boost::python::object getNumpyArray(std::vector<T>& vector)
{
    npy_intp shape[1] = { vector.size() };
    //Here I would need to replace NPY_DOUBLE with some conversion of T
    PyObject* obj = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, shape, NPY_DOUBLE, vector.data());
    boost::python::handle<> handle(obj);
    boost::python::numeric::array arr(handle);

    return arr.copy();
}
```

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065183/convert-a-stdvector-to-a-numpy-array-without-copying-data

Comment: @NathanOliver The question you link to (or at least the answer) is almost identical to the one I link to but does not provide any info on how to employ templates to avoid code copy-pasting using `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData`, which is basically my question. So I think my question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own trait which will select numpy type based on c++ type, for example:

```
template <typename T>
struct select_npy_type
{};

template <>
struct select_npy_type<double>
{
    const static NPY_TYPES type = NPY_DOUBLE;
};

template <>
struct select_npy_type<float>
{
    const static NPY_TYPES type = NPY_FLOAT;
};

template <>
struct select_npy_type<int>
{
    const static NPY_TYPES type = NPY_INT;
};
```

And then:

```
PyObject* obj = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, shape, select_npy_type<T>::type, vector.data());
```