# Recoding itoa: error on minimum int

Tags: c

I am trying to recode the itoa function which, given a int, will return a string representing its decimal value. So far, the functions works well:

```
char        *ft_itoa(int n)
{
    char    s[1024];
    int     i;
    int     neg;

    i = 0;
    neg = 0;
    if (n == 0)
        s[i++] = '0';
    if (n < 0)
    {
        n = n * (-1);
        neg = 1;
    }
    while (n != 0)
    {
        s[i++] = (n % 10) + 48;
        n /= 10;
    }
    if (neg)
        s[i++] = '-';
    s[i] = '\0';
    return (ft_strrev(s));
}
```

Except for the minimum int value, -2147483648. In that case, the function returns:

```
"-./,),(-*,("
```

Wich is... weird. Note that ft_strrev will reverse the result and malloc it. Any clues?

**EDIT:**

There are quite interesting answers here. I am specially interested in the minium size of the buffer. Using limits.h seems to do the trick, but **I am not allowed** to include other headers than stdlib.h and string.h. I am also limited in three functions, malloc, free and write. However, I did recode strdup and a lot of functions from libc.

Could someone explain why that line would declare the exact amount of memory I need:

```
char   buf[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT / 3 + 3];
```

Also,

> Using unsigned to compute the digits would avoid the problem with INT_MIN. Bug fix for INT_MIN.

Why?

Comment: Please post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `-2147483648` * `-1` is overflow in 32bit int.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY shouldn't the limit be the same on both signs? I don't get that.

Comment: 32bit int max value is `2147483647`.

Comment: zero is included as well in the total range of numbers so there is one less number for the positive signed numbers.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Okay, I guess it has to do with the fact that the count of elements is a power of 2, therefore being a pair number, then if you include 0 you can't have the same amount in both sides. Anyway thanks, question answered.

Comment: @qleguennec: actually, it depends from the representation of numbers; if you go with sign and magnitude (as floating point generally do) you have the same limit on both sides, but you have two zeroes (+0 and -0); but for integers on any reasonable platform (=> which employs 2's complement arithmetic) you can rest assured that the range is -2^(n-1) ... 2^(n-1)-1 (where n is the size of the integer in bits).

Answer (score 2):

There are several small issues with your code:

- The buffer is much too large: including sign and null terminator, 24 bytes should suffice. For absolute portability, an upper bound of `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3` is correct. *Not a bug, but wasteful*.
- If you store the digits into the buffer from right to left, you don't need the final reverse phase and could call `strdup()` directly. *Simpler and faster*.
- Using `unsigned` to compute the digits would avoid the problem with INT_MIN. *Bug fix for INT_MIN*.
- Looping for `i >= 10` and storing the final digit separately avoids the special case for `0`. *Simpler and faster, fewer divisions*.
- You should use `'0'` instead of hard coding ASCII value `48`. *More readable and portable*.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <limits.h>

char *ft_itoa(int n) {
    char buf[sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3];
    char *s;
    unsigned int v;

    v = n;
    if (n < 0) {
        v = -v;
    }
    s = buf + sizeof(buf);
    *--s = '\0';
    while (v >= 10) {
        *--s = '0' + v % 10;
        v /= 10;
    }
    *--s = '0' + v;
    if (n < 0)
        *--s = '-';
    return strdup(s);
}
```

If `strdup` is not available on your system, it is easy to implement and quite useful if you allocate strings from the heap.

Comment: Corner case: Using `unsigned`, in general works to cope with `INT_MIN`.  Yet C does not specify that `UINT_MAX > INT_MAX`.  Odd ball platforms use a sign bit for `int` and have `UINT_MAX == INT_MAX` and `-INT_MIN` is not representable as an `unsigned`.

Comment: @chux: true but a very theoretical point these days.  All odd ball platforms I know that have `UINT_MAX == INT_MAX` also use sign/magnitude representation, and therefore `-INT_MIN` is representable as an `unsigned`.  I'd be interested to see and operate your vintage DS9K for fun `;-)`.

Comment: @chux: I was expecting a more general remark such as: *you assume 2's complement*.  Indeed `v = -v` avoids integer overflow but might not produce the expected value on (hypothetical) non 2's complement hardware.

Comment: In looking over source coded for highly portable, came across the the summing technique on the negative side of `int`, rather than the positive side.  The useful attribute is that since it does not use `unsigned` at all, that type's properties  compared to `int` are moot.  Some find it more difficult to follow, but it does work

Comment: How is 2^63 relevant to this?

Comment: @M.M: 2^63 is just a silly practical limit, I guess I should use `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3` for the buffer size.

Comment: @chux: your technique is more portable but relies on C99 that first mandated truncation toward 0 for integer division.  Under C89, the sign of `i%10` for negative `i` is implementation defined.

Comment: Can you explain `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3`? What is CHAR_BIT?

Comment: @qleguennec: `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT` is the number of bits in an `int`. 3 bits encode 8 different values, which is less than 10. hence `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 1` is an upper bound for the number of decimal digits. Add 1 for the `'\0'` and 1 for the minus sign.  This is an upper bound, for 32 bit ints, `4*8/3+3` = `13`, whereas `-2147483648\0` fits in just `12` bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `int` overflow (`if (n < 0) { n = n * (-1);` which caused OP's problem) and embraced the dark (negative) side.  Since there are more negative `int` than positive ones, sum on the negative side.

```
#include <limits.h>
char *ft_itoa(int n) {
  char s[50];
  // char s[1024];
  int i;
  int neg;

  i = 0;
  neg = 0;
  //if (n == 0)          // special case not need with do loop
  //    s[i++] = '0';

  if (n < 0) {           // Insure n is _not_ positive
    // n = n * (-1);
    neg = 1;
  } else {
    n = -n;              // no overflow possible here
  }
  // while (n != 0)
  do {
    // s[i++] = (n % 10) + 48;
    s[i++] = '0' - (n % 10);   // subtract
    n /= 10;
  } while (n);
  if (neg) s[i++] = '-';
  s[i] = '\0';
  return strdup(strrev(s));
}
```

For a cleaned-up version

```
#include <limits.h>

// Compute max size need to represent an `int`
#define INT_DEC_SIZE (sizeof (int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3)

char *ft_itoa(int n) {
  char s[INT_DEC_SIZE];
  char *p = &s[sizeof s - 1];
  *p = '\0';
  int i = n;
  if (i > 0) {
    i = -i;
  }
  do {
    p--;
    *p = '0' - (i % 10);
    i /= 10;
  } while (i);
  if (n < 0) *(--p) = '-';
  return strdup(p);
}
```

[INT_DEC_SIZE ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32420518/2410359)

Comment: Using `static` persistent memory is **perverse!**  The OP explicitly says the result is allocated, why remove this feature and introduce potential hard to find bugs?

Comment: @chqrlie Did not notice OP's `strrev()` with `malloc()`.  Code amended.

Comment: You should include `<limits.h>` for `CHAR_BIT` in the cleaned-up version

Comment: @chqrlie My compile pick-up up `CHAR_BIT` when `stdlib.h` was included. Agree  `<limits.h>` is the better header file.

Comment: Although `strdup` is not a standard function, it is usually declared in `<stdlib.h>` so both are needed.