# Custom Width Variables

Tags: c++

Is there any simple way to have a custom width variable? I know you can

```
void* foo = new unsigned char[ 40 ];
// foo points to some var that needs 40 bytes of data to contain it
```

and then cast & dereference foo and modify it based on the size of the type you cast it to.

I was wondering if there was something more genius, perhaps using unions.

```
union
{
public:
    unsigned int data; // how you want to treat the data based on this var's datatype
private:
    unsigned char reserved[ 40 ]; // actual size of data
} foo;

foo.data = 20u; // unfortunately, this only affects 8* bytes of the full 40 reserved...
```

Comment: You could just use a class

Comment: I just wonder how "this only affects 8* bytes" works.

Comment: can you explain a bit more what you want and why you want it? cuz parts of your question might lead to [`alignas`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) but its not clear

Comment: An object **is** the bytes that make up it's representation. It cannot change size. Are you asking about `reinterpret_cast`ing the address of a T to a `char *` (+ a `sizeof T` length) and using those bytes?

Comment: What you want to achieve?It sounds a bit that you think in python or some other scripting language, where variables can be "assigned" to any size/data type ever and ever again. But c++ is a strictly typed language. So there is also a other "mindset" to write programs. For changing types see std::variant or std::any. If you change size dynamic, use container classes like std::vector or maybe std::string. You also may use a combination like std::vector<std::variant>. But the first question still is: What you really need! Unions, also std::variant, always uses the memory of the biggest used type.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this statement in your question:

```
void* foo = new unsigned char[ 40 ];
```

is allocating 40 bytes of `unsigned char` type on the free-store (or heap) i.e. dynamic memory allocation. You can simply avoid pointer operations e.g. casting, increment, decrement, de-reference, etc. by using an array on stack like this:

```
unsigned char foo[ 40 ];
```

That is the case when you already know the size e.g. 40 in your question.

So, there are two types of arrays according to lengths: fixed and variable. Fixed-length that you know at compile-time; and, variable-length that you get at run-time. And, from your question, the term "custom" might be referring to "variable-length arrays".

---

You cannot have a variable-length array on stack in standard C++ so you have to allocate it on free-store using `new[]` and de-allocate after use using `delete[]`. Though, some compiler extensions also allow variable-length arrays e.g. GCC (See: [C++ : Variable Length Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318007/c-variable-length-array)).

So, if you have an array size that you don't know already then the dynamic memory allocation is way to go.

Or, you can simply use an STL container such as [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). It'll handle all the memory management stuff under the hood. And, you can simply start writing your business logic right away instead of spending time on memory management. And, for static fixed-length arrays, you ought to use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) with all the good stuff that come with it.

And, if you really want to do memory management stuff yourself, you ought to look at [`std::unqiue_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) along with [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) and [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) wherever applicable depending on your use-cases. That would make life easy by enforcing [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

As you're working with raw bytes (guessed it from `unsigned char`), you ought to use [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) if you can have a C++17-enabled compiler.

---

Relevant material:

- [C++, Free-Store vs Heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350819/c-free-store-vs-heap)
- [C++ : Variable Length Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318007/c-variable-length-array)
- [What is meant by Resource Acquisition is Initialization (RAII)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii)

---

Hope that helps!
If there is more to your use-case, kindly add that detail in your question so that the answer could be more relevant and aligned to that specific use-case.

Answer (score 0):

From high to low level:

- [`std::variant<..>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) — a type safe union, capable of holding an instance of one of finite set of types at a time, aligned, non-empty
- [`std::aligned_storage<..>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) and [`std::aligned_union<..>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_union) — a foundation building block for when `std::variant<..>` is too much or not exactly right
- [`alignas`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) and [`std::align`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) — lowest level building blocks