# Having trouble passing lines from txt file to array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, fstream

I feel like I'm completely missing out on something but my compiler shows absolutely nothing when i test out if my array is getting filled with values from the txt file.

```
void orderID(){
  ifstream result;

  int flag;
  int loop = 0;
  string temp;

  string line;
  string myArray[flag];

  result.open("resultat.txt");
  while(getline(result, line)){
    flag++; //number of lines in file
  }
  result.close();

  result.open("resultat.txt");
  while(getline(result, line)){
    myArray[loop] = line;
    loop++;
    cout<< myArray[1];
  }
  result.close();
}
```

Should probably post the txt file im testing. It should work with any file though.

```
21 para 21 first
23 dyta 23 second
11 katert 11 fourth
12 pest 12 fifth
13 fundit 13 last
14 jojo 14 nono
```

Anyone knows what I'm missing here? Btw please do not suggest vectors as I can not use them for this scenario. And yes I am calling the function from int main.

Comment: Did you initialize `flag = 0;`?

Comment: The same issue occurs.
EDIT: Before I used to test cout<<flag to see if the flag works and it used to, right now it's not working anymore after i tested out ways to fix my original problem...

Comment: How do you expect the array to be the right size if you declare it before you even know how big it should be? Also C++ does not have variable-length arrays, use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I literally said I can't use vectors. I'm a beginner who has this language in school, you don't have to ask me more questions, I already have plenty of them myself.

Comment: use cout<<myArray[loop]; for better debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize myArray with the correct size, which means after you compute the flag not while it is undefined

```
void orderID(){
  ifstream result;

  int flag = 0;
  int loop = 0;
  string temp;

  string line;

  result.open("resultat.txt");
  while(getline(result, line)){
    flag++; //number of lines in file
  }
  result.close();

  string myArray[flag];

  result.open("resultat.txt");
  while(getline(result, line)){
    myArray[loop] = line;
    loop++;
    cout<< myArray[1];
  }
  result.close();
}
```

Comment: It's true what you said. I had to introduce the array a bit later. Thank you very much for the solution

Comment: This is not according to the C++ standard ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318007/c-variable-length-array](C++ VLA)). For dynamic arrays, when std::vector can't be used for whatever reason, new[]/delete[] should be used. It is supported by several compilers, so if it works for you, that's fine. Beware that larger arrays can cause stack-overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your input but I literally do not understand half the things you have mentioned xd. I'm sure I will get to learn them in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit of a misunderstanding here:

```
int flag; // uninitialised, this value could be anything
...
string myArray[flag]; // 1. you haven't set flag, how can we know how big this is
                      // 2. VLA are non-standard c++, you can't do this so easily
```

Since you have said you cannot use a `std::vector` which is a bit of a bummer, you will need to handle the memory yourself. That means using `new[]` and `delete[]`. Something like this:

```
int flag = 0
// Use your loop to find out the size of the vector
string* myArray = new string[flag]
// use myArray the same way (aka, get things with myArray[myIndex])
// make sure you check for out of bounds operations
delete[] myArray // This is super important, when you use new, you must use delete.
```

This is the basic approach, but to really wow, your teacher, just write a minimal vector! What do we need for this?

1. Something that we construct that only has the correct size possible.
2. A way to access the elements.
3. Correct destruction.

So something like this would suffice:

```
class MyVector {
  public:
    MyVector(unsigned size) { // Constructor for a specific size
        array_ = new string[size];
    }

    string& operator[](unsigned index) { // A way to access the elements
        return array_[index];
    }

    ~MyVector() { // A way to destroy it
        delete[] array_;
    }

    // You should really delete copy constructor and others (rule of 5) but that
    // is a little advanced for this. 

  private:
    string* array_;

};
```

Then you can use it in your code quite nicely:

```
int flag = 0
// ...
MyVector myArray(flag);
// ...
    myArray[someIndex] = someThing;
//...
//... No need to delete, that is handled by the class.
```

It is safe (well, safer), a little bit re-usable, and well encapsulated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to initialize `myArray` with a variable as the array length, which is not allowed in C++.

Since you can't use vectors in this code, you'll need to allocate space to the array using the `new` operator.

So first, you'll need to initialize `flag` to 0. Then, once you've counted the number of lines in the file, create `myArray` likewise:

```
string *myArray = new string[flag];
```

What this line does, is that it allocates memory on the heap for `myArray` with the size of `flags`.

So your code should look something like this:

```
flag = 0;
while(getline(result, line)){
    flag++;
}
string *myArray = new string[flag];
//...
delete[] myArray;
```

Once you're done with the array, you can de-allocate your array using the `delete[]` operator.