# C++ how to convert vector to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Can someone be able to tell me how to convert vector to an array?
I have a function that returns a vector of double type with typical like this

```
std::vector<double>  x_vec = LinspaceArray_DK2(0, 5.0, 0.01);
std::vector<double>  y_vec = Calculate_y_vec(x_vec);
```

However, following GSL (GNU scientific lib) function is expecting an array as an input

```
gsl_spline_init (spline, x_array, y_array, x_vec.length);
```

Here, x_array, y_array are arrays corresponding to vectors x_vec and y_vec.

I tried following solution here ([How to convert vector to array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923272/how-to-convert-vector-to-array-c)) which suggest conversion like this:

```
std::vector<double> v;
double* a = &v[0];
```

But, this type of conversion did not help with gsl_spline_init which expected arrays as inputs.

**Updated:**

I tried to call like this:

```
// Convert all vector to an array
double* x_input_Array = &x_input[0];
double* y_input_Array = &y_input[0];
```

and then call:

```
gsl_spline_init (spline, *x_input_Array, *y_input_Array, iNoOfPtsIni);
```

I am getting this error:
error C2664: 'gsl_spline_init' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'double' to 'const double []'

Thanks,
DK

Comment: What do you mean by "did not help"? Show how you call gsl_spline_init and what errors you get.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka : I updated my question to include how I called gsl_spline_init function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need (and should not) dereference - the function you call expects arrays, and you pass their first elements. Use

```
gsl_spline_init (spline, x_input_Array, y_input_Array, iNoOfPtsIni);
```

Comment: Thanks @WojtekSurowka : it worked. However, I am confused about pointer to arrays. As gsl_spline_init needs arrays as input; how inputing pointer works out fine? Do you know any online resources for clearing my doubts about arrays?

Comment: @DushyantKumar The function doesn't want *arrays* (even it the arguments are named that way), it wants *pointers*. Always remember that arrays, when passed as arguments to functions, decays to pointers. So even if an argument is declared with array-like syntax (like `double x_array[]`) the argument is still a pointer.

Comment: @DushyantKumar Try e.g. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays#Pointers_and_Arrays

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : Thanks for explaining to me. One more question. How does similar conversion works for function with input as reference? Can I still pass pointer?