# C++ Reading Characters from Text File to Dynamically Allocated Array

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory

I am relatively new to C++, and I am attempting to read sequenceofchars from a text file into a char array that is dynamically allocated. My code is as follows:

```
while (file.get(c))
{
    if (c =='\n')
        continue;

    char *temp = new char[i++];
    arrayA = new char[i++];
    arrayA[i] = c;
    delete [] arrayA;
    arrayA = temp;
}
```

And the text file format is as follows:

```
>NameOfChars
sequenceofchars
```

This is obviously horribly broken, but I've struggled to figure out the exact methodology one would use to go through this. I know about the Vector class, but I am unsure about how to go about using that if that is the preferred method for reallocating arrays on the heap. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should definitely take a look at the vector class since it would make your code a lot cleaner. Here is a small (untested) code sample of how to use it:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<char> my_vector;

while (file.get(c))
{
    if (c =='\n')
        continue;

    my_vector.push_back(c);
}
```

For more information please check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/

Comment: Would I be able to convert the vector to a char array in the end?

Comment: Yes you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923272/how-to-convert-vector-to-array-c

Answer (score 0):

A raw array isn't dynamically allocated; hence using an STL container like vector would be better.

```
ifstream inf;
char c;
vector<char> charVec;

while (inf >> c)
{
    charVec.push_back(c);
}
```