# Conversion from vector to array: length becomes exactly 4

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have a vector of chars:

```
vector<char> bytesv;
```

I push 1024 chars to this vector in a loop (not important to the context) using push_back(char):

```
bytesv.push_back(c);
```

I know this vector has an exact value of 1024. It indeeds print `1024` when doing the following:

```
cout << bytesv.size() << "\n";
```

*What I am trying to do:* **I need to transform this vector into a char array (char[]) of the same length and elements  as  the vector. I do the following:**

```
char* bytes = &bytesv[0];
```

*The problem:* But when I print the size of this array, it prints `4`, so the size is not what I expected:

```
cout << sizeof(bytes) << "\n";
```

Full code:

```
vector<char> bytesv;

for (char c : charr) { // Not important, there are 1024 chars in this array
    bytesv.push_back(c);
}
cout << bytesv.size() << "\n";
char* bytes = &bytesv[0];
cout << sizeof(bytes) << "\n";
```

Prints:

```
1024
4
```

This obviously has to do with the fact that `bytes` is actually a `char*`, not really an array AFAIK. 
*The question:* **How can I safely transfer all the vector's contents into an array, then?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert vector to array C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923272/how-to-convert-vector-to-array-c)

Comment: *I need to transform this vector into a char array (char[]) of the same length and elements as the vector.*  Why?  A `vector<char>` internally *is* a char array that is just wrapped.  Just call `vector::data()` to access the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I safely transfer all the vector's contents into an array, then?

1. Allocate the required memory by using dynamic memory allocation.

   ```
   size_t size = bytesv.size();
   char* char_array = new char[size];
   ```
2. Copy the elements from the vector to the array.

   ```
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
      char_array[i] = bytesv[i];
   ```
3. Make sure you deallocate the memory after you are done using it.

   ```
   delete [] char_array;
   ```

Having said, that I realized that you mentioned in a comment,

> My ultimate goal is to save these bytes to a file, using `fstream`, which requires an array of chars as far as I am concerned.

You don't need to copy the contents of the vector to an array to save them to an `fstream`. The contents of a `std::vector` are guaranteed to be in contiguous memory. You can just use:

```
outStream.write(bytesv.data(), bytesv.size());
```

Comment: Correct but unnecessary

Comment: `delete[]` is missing, you leak memory.

Comment: @developerbmw. which part do you think is unnecessary?

Comment: @RSahu the copy. The OP mentioned in a comment that he needs the char array for outputting to a file so there is no specific need to have a complete copy of the data. But I appreciate that it's not actually in the question so still a good answer :)

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(bytes)` is the size of the pointer, not what it points to. Also,

```
char* bytes = &bytesv[0];
```

Doesn't transfer anything to an array, all you've done is saved a pointer to the beginning of the underlying array in `std::vector`.

To correctly move the data to an array you'll need to dynamically allocate an array. But the question is why would you do that? You already have a vector. It's like an array but about a billion times better.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to save these bytes to a file, using fstream, which requires an array of chars as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @Momo Then you should just be able to use your "bytes" variable as you have it coded and get the length from the vector.

Comment: "You already have a vector. It's like an array but about a billion times better." +1

Answer (score 1):

> How can I safely transfer all the vector's contents into an array, then?

There's no need to "transfer" (i.e. copy). You can access the vector's underlying storage as an array by using the `data` method.

`char* arr = bytesv.data();`

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data

> bytes is actually a char*, not really an array

The `char*` is not an array but a pointer to the first value in the array. You can get the number of elements in the array from `bytesv.size()`

Comment: The question OP asked was to " transfer all the vector's contents into an array" - not to "access the vector like an array". So copy operation IS necessary.

Comment: @Constantin, not strictly true since OP mentioned in another comment of the ultimate goal of writing the data to a file with `fstream`.

Comment: @Constantin given that the OP tried using this `char* bytes = &bytesv[0];` obviously he doesn't actually need a copy. He just wants to access the data in an array form.

Comment: @developerbmw No, that's not obvious as the question states something else. He's a beginner so it's more likely, that he doesn't understand the basics of memory management (and that a copy operation is necessary to "transfer" data from a `vector` to an array). His question was not: How to write a `vector` to a file using `fstream`: You didn't answer the question he raised, but a specific problem which is not part of the question - this is irritating for anyone who finds this question in the future if they want to do what OP has asked in his initially question.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `sizeof` any pointer is 4 (on a 32 bit target).  What

```
char* bytes = &bytesv[0];
```

is giving you is a pointer to the first element, not, necessarily, an array of chars.

now if you used:

```
char (*bytes)[1024] = (char (*)[1024])&v[0];
std::cout << sizeof(bytes) << " " << sizeof(*bytes);
```

that would give you a pointer to a 'char[1024]' array.

Comment: @developerbmw, well to for simple pointers (to my understanding). Pointer-to-member will probably depend on the structure of the class hierarchy.

Comment: @developerbmw **facepalm** ::blush:: it's late here, not thinking completely clearly, I guess. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, we all have those moments :)

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(bytes)` is always 4 because `*bytes` is a pointer and you are using a machine that uses 4-byte pointers.

You already know that you have 1024 bytes; just use that knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you need to copy the content of the vector to the array - otherwise you can't access elements of your array, when the vector is gone. So you need to allocate memory to your array (not just defining a pointer).

```
char* bytes = new char[bytesv.size()];
for (size_t i = 0; i < bytesv.size(); ++i) {
  bytes [i] = bytesv.at(i);
}
//...
delete[] bytes;
```

Secondly [sizeof()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) doesn't do what you expect: its not reporting the length of an array, but the size of a type/pointer. In case of stack allocated arrays, it can be used as: `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);` to determine the size, but as `sizeof()` is a compile time operator it can't know the size of your dynamic allocated arrays or vectors.

If you use an array, you need to use a seperate variable to store the length of this array (alternatively you could use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  std::vector<uint8_t> bytesv = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06 };
  size_t bytesLength = bytesv.size();
  char* bytes = new char[bytesLength];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < bytesv.size(); ++i) {
    bytes[i] = bytesv.at(i);
  }
  //...
  std::cout << bytesLength << std::endl;
  delete[] bytes;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need to use the slower `at()`, use `operator[]`