# How to convert a vector of integer arrays into a 2D array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector

So I have been looking at the following post for converting a vector into an array but this method does not seem to be converting for my use case.

[How to convert vector to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923272/how-to-convert-vector-to-array)

```
vector<array<int, 256>> table; // is my table that I want to convert

// There is then code in the middle that will fill it

int** convert = &table[0][0] // is the first method that I attempted

convert = table.data(); // is the other method to convert that doesn't work
```

I belive my understanding of the back end of the data type is where my knowledge falls short. Any help on this would be appreciated

edit: I have changed form C style array's to C++ arrays

Comment: `vector<int[256]>` looks weird already, it probably should be `std::vector<std::array<int,256>>`

Comment: I don't think you can use `vector<int[256]>` in practice in the first place. How do you insert elements into it?

Comment: An array decays to a pointer (`int *` in this case). An array of arrays  decays to a pointer to an array (`int *[SIZE]`), not a double pointer. Taking the address of `table[0][0]` provides a pointer to that one element, an `int *`. Making a 2D array out of `int **` takes a bit of work and is often the least efficient way to do the job. There's probably a good formal answer embedded in this comment if I try hard enough to eke it out.

Comment: As far as it stands eerorika and πάντα ῥεῖ I have had no issues in regards to using the C style array but I am now looking at redoing this as a CPP array to see if this fixes my issue

Comment: @yeroc_sebrof Well, the major problem I see is that neither `vector<int[256]>` nor `std::vector<std::array<int,256>>` would store the data in a single, consecutive chunk of memory, thus a simple cast can't be applied.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I woudl expect that to be incorrect given the answer to the question I linked to. I will look into the answer Anroca provided first before looking into other methods

Comment: @yeroc_sebrof No, what I said isn't _incorrect_. Using a simple cast is something fundamentally different as doing a copy.

Comment: @eerorika by pushing an pre-initalised row I have stored. `int newRow[256] = { 0 };`

Comment: @yeroc_sebrof I can't get that working: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2499f9b3ed7216e Can you show me a minimal demo of how to use it?

Comment: @yeroc_sebrof The native pointer arithmetic coming with a `int**` would calculate offsets based on a consecutive memory block that can be addressed with the simple formula _`addr = base_addr + (row_index * row_size) + col_index`

Comment: @eerorika, it seems I had too much trust in IntelliSense. It seems that this method does not work. Thank you for bringing this to my attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is going to be a route that should work via casting, the easiest thing I can guarantee will work is to make an array of pointers to `int`s that contains pointers to the arrays in the source `vector`.

```
// make vector of pointers to int
std::vector<int*> table2(table.size());

// fill pointer vector pointers to arrays in array vector
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
{
    table2[i] = table[i];
}
```

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <memory>

constexpr int size = 4;

// test by printing out 
void func(int ** arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++ )
        {
            std::cout << std::setw(5) << arr[i][j] <<  ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int[size]> table(size);

    // fill values
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++ )
        {
            table[i][j] = i*size +j;
        }
    }

    // build int **
    std::vector<int*> table2(table.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        table2[i] = table[i];
    }

    //call function
    func(table2.data());

}
```

Looks like you're stuck doing this he thar way because of the requirement for a `int **`, when possible try to use [a simple matrix class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming use of C++ 11, `include <algorithm>`

you could probably use std::copy.

I've not tested it but believe you could just do:

```
std::copy(&table[0][0], &table[0][0]+256*table.size(), &myArray[0][0]);
```

where the parameters are effectively:

```
std::copy(<source obj begin>, <source obj end>, <dest obj begin>);
```

More on that here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy