# How to pass an array by void pointer in C/C++

Tags: c++, pthreads

The function interface being used requires a single generic void pointer argument:

```
void* function(void* p_void) { ... }
```

The argument I need to pass happens to be an array of objects. Let's go back to something simpler; for a normal datatype, it's possible to write:

```
void* function(void* p_void) {
    type* p_object = static_cast<type*>(p_void);
}
```

Is replacing this type of syntax for arrays possible? If it is, I'm not sure how that works -- how would the function know how long the array is?

Is there a reference that shows how to do this? Something like `Range[]* p_array = static_cast<[Range]*>(p_void)` obviously doesn't work in C.

Comment: You need to pass also the number of elements in the array.

Comment: And then do some pointer arithmetic or array indexing on each element.  As an aside, C and C++ are two different languages.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  In C++, you'd probably use a template.

Comment: @NathanOliver C++, the reason I mention C is that it's actually using C libraries and compiled in gcc then using the g++ linker.

Comment: Why not use a vector? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923272/how-to-convert-vector-to-array for how to convert it to an array when calling the C library.

Comment: @Barmar the function I'm actually calling is `pthread_create()`. I'm not sure about the implications for thread safety.

Comment: The implications should be no different than for a normal array. Just make sure you don't access the vector in multiple threads.

Comment: C and C++ have two *completely* different approaches here. Please don't conflate the two.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using `sdt::thread` so you can avoid all of this `void*` trouble?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, it's an assignment on `pthread`.

Comment: @Barmar your idea works, sort of. Because the address to the vector is held in shared memory, concurrent threads get confused about which vector they are pointing to, causing faults.